# Serial Port Plotting

Tags: vb.net, timer, arduino, serial-port, delay

I have an arduino nano and it's going to behave like a voltmeter
It reads ADC (analog port A0) then sends the data from serial port to computer and i designed a visual basic program to read these data and plot it in a chart.
but somehow timer in vb and delay in arduino wouldn't sync sometimes and it returns false values. what can i do ?
 [False Value's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn3Ln.jpg)

VB side code :

```
  Private Sub connect_BTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles connect_BTN.Click
        Try
            If (connect_BTN.Text = "Connect") Then
                If (comPORT <> "") Then

                    SerialPort1.Close()
                    SerialPort1.PortName = comPORT
                    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                    SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                    SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
                    SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
                    SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
                    SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!
                    SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10000

                    SerialPort1.Open()
                    connect_BTN.Text = "Dis-connect"
                    'Timer1.Enabled = True
                    'Timer_LBL.Text = "Timer: ON"
                    STATUS.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
                Else
                    MsgBox("Select a COM port first")
                End If
            Else
                SerialPort1.Close()
                connect_BTN.Text = "Connect"
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                Timer_LBL.Text = "Timer: OFF"
                STATUS.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        Catch exx As Exception
            MsgBox(exx.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
      Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
        RichTextBox1.Text += receivedData & vbCrLf
        Dim meghdar As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(receivedData)
        s.Points.AddY(meghdar)
    End Sub
    Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
        Try
            Dim Incoming As String
            Try
                Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
                If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                    Return 0
                Else
                    Return Convert.ToInt32(Incoming)
                End If
            Catch ex As TimeoutException
                Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
Arduino Code :

    /*
  SD card datalogger

 The circuit:
 * analog sensors on analog ins 0, 1, and 2
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4 (for MKRZero SD: SDCARD_SS_PIN)
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  //Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // see if the card is present and can be init-ialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    //Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }
 // Serial.println("card initialized.");
   File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
   if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println("ConePenetroMeter TEST results :");
    dataFile.close();
    // print to the serial port too:
    //Serial.println("ConePenetroMeter TEST results :");

  }
}

void loop() {
  // make a string for assembling the data to log:
  String dataString = "";

  // read three sensors and append to the string:

    int sensor = analogRead(A0);
    dataString += String(sensor);

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file is available, write to it:
  if (dataFile) {

    dataFile.println(dataString);
    dataFile.close();
    // print to the serial port too:
    Serial.println(sensor);

  }
  // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
  else {
    //Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
  }
  delay(300);
}
```

delay in arduino is 300 ms and timer interval in vb.net is 300 ms also

Comment: It is the usual problem with ReadExisting().  If you do it right then you only get 1 or 2 bytes, not a value.  You must be sure to get *all* the bytes.  That is not hard when you use println() in the Arduino, just use ReadLine() in C#.  Since you are not using the DataReceived event, be sure to only call it when BytesToRead is larger than 0 so you'll know that ReadLine() will not block and will not throw an exception.  And do it in a loop so you can't fall behind.

Comment: Can you send a code please ? i get it but i don't know exactly how it works

Comment: You might send data binary as single bytes, which should usually have sufficient accuracy to display a graph. Your `ReceiveSerialData` is declared to return a String but you do `Return Convert.ToInt32(Incoming)`  ? ? ?